# How to parse JSON response in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I'm using a Google AdWords/App Script and I got this response from DoubleClick Search. I'm trying to parse it to put in a Sheet/ into an array to work with and I'm not having much luck. Thank you for taking a look.

This is the original code:

```
var response = authUrlFetch.fetch(url, options);
 var data = JSON.stringify(response.getContentText());
 var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

{
 "kind": "doubleclicksearch#report",
 "request": {
  "reportType": "advertiser",
  "columns": [
   {
    "columnName": "agency"
   },
   {
    "columnName": "agencyId"
   },
   {
    "columnName": "advertiser"
   },
   {
    "columnName": "advertiserId"
   }
  ],
  "includeRemovedEntities": false,
  "statisticsCurrency": "usd",
  "startRow": 0,
  "rowCount": 10000
 },
 "statisticsCurrencyCode": "USD",
 "rowCount": 2,
 "rows": [
  {
   "agency": "a",
   "agencyId": "11111111111111",
   "advertiser": "aa",
   "advertiserId": "11111111111111"
  },
  {
   "agency": "b",
   "agencyId": "222222222222222",
   "advertiser": "bb",
   "advertiserId": "22222222222"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: When I Google `How to parse JSON response in Google App Script?` I seem to be getting lots of results. Is none of them helpful?

Comment: I'm looking around, but I can't find how to do this with how the JSON is set up. I'm currently stuck, but still looking. Thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is similar to regular JavaScript. You get the JSON response with `UrlFetchApp` service and then access the properties using the dot notation.

```
try {
    const response = UrlfetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(data.request.reportType);
} catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.message);
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, what is dot notation? I tried your code but it says
TypeError: Cannot read property "reportType" from undefined - what am i doing wrong? Also had to use UrlFetchApp instead of authUrlFetch

Comment: your json retrieved does not have property type reportType. @esaruoho

Answer (score 3):

Variation of the first answer when working with apis

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(externalposturl).getContentText();
var data = JSON.parse(response);
Logger.log(data.message);
```