# How to parse JSON provided by GitHub API to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, github-api

I'm doing multiple queries (find amount of open/closed issues, use the open/closed issues (per person) to create a leaderboard of developer issue closes, etc - find how many issues were closed this week and how many opened last week - what's the newest issue, what's the oldest issue) to GitHub's API and trying to get the resultant data written onto a Google Sheet. I'm using Google Apps Script Editor to do this.

I can get the JSON data from GitHub API to the console no problem, but I'm not sure how to then parse and write it to Google Sheets. How could I do this, please?

An example of a JSON data (this time it was "open issues" grabbed from http://github.com/vizorvr/patches/ )

```
[17-08-08 13:47:46:353 EEST] {"total_count":271,"incomplete_results":false,"items":[{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2035","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2035/labels{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2035/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2035/events","html_url":"https://github.com/vizorvr/patches/issues/2035","id":245953104,"number":2035,"title":"Figure out which Three.JS plugins are missing from Patches and add them","user":{"login":"esaruoho","id":4966687,"avatar_url":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/4966687?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho","html_url":"https://github.com/esaruoho","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":null,"assignees":[],"milestone":null,"comments":0,"created_at":"2017-07-27T07:41:52Z","updated_at":"2017-07-27T07:41:52Z","closed_at":null,"body":"Go to http://threejs.org and compare the list of ThreeJS plugins in Patches and what is available on the ThreeJS site. Then implement them.","score":1.0},{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2034","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2034/labels{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2034/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2034/events","html_url":"https://github.com/vizorvr/patches/issues/2034","id":245952930,"number":2034,"title":"Inspect the Radial Point Geometry -plugin and figure out what it does or should do","user":{"login":"esaruoho","id":4966687,"avatar_url":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/4966687?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho","html_url":"https://github.com/esaruoho","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":null,"assignees":[],"milestone":null,"comments":0,"created_at":"2017-07-27T07:41:07Z","updated_at":"2017-07-27T07:41:07Z","closed_at":null,"body":"Go into Patches and add the Radial Point Geometry -patch.\r\n\r\nStudy what it does. Figure if it does anything. If it does something, come up with an example explaining how it should be used - then help with the popup documentation.\r\n\r\n![vizor](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4966687/28659400-fb6f7a5c-72b7-11e7-83c9-6da26fe5ce13.png)\r\n","score":1.0},{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2023","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2023/labels{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2023/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2023/events","html_url":"https://github.com/vizorvr/patches/issues/2023","id":241289959,"number":2023,"title":"Shortcut: Shift-Tab: improve by opening \"Inspector->Properties\"","user":{"login":"esaruoho","id":4966687,"avatar_url":"https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/4966687?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho","html_url":"https://github.com/esaruoho","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/esaruoho/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[{"id":165125694,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/labels/enhancement","name":"enhancement","color":"84b6eb","default":true},{"id":346495796,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/labels/user","name":"user","color":"fbca04","default":false},{"id":270777736,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/labels/UX","name":"UX","color":"5319e7","default":false}],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":{"login":"gmarinov","id":14101296,"avatar_url":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/14101296?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov","html_url":"https://github.com/gmarinov","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"assignees":[{"login":"gmarinov","id":14101296,"avatar_url":"https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/14101296?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov","html_url":"https://github.com/gmarinov","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/gmarinov/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false}],"milestone":null,"comments":0,"created_at":"2017-07-07T14:57:29Z","updated_at":"2017-07-07T15:44:19Z","closed_at":null,"body":"Improve Shift-Tab so that it opens the Inspector ( press I ) AND selects Properties-tab instead of Node.\r\n\r\n","score":1.0},{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2022","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2022/labels{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2022/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/vizorvr/patches/issues/2022/events","html_url":"https://github.com/vizorvr/patches/issues/2022","id":24086639
```

I have, thus far, grabbed something called pullJSON to try and pull the data, which looks like this - however, unfortunately it seems destructive - it does not write to a specific sheet, just any old active sheet. I'm not sure how to modify it to write it to a specific sheet so that it'll work, so that's why I'm asking about how to parse stuff.

```
function pullJSON() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var url="https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:vizorvr/patches+state:closed"; // Paste your JSON URL here

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;

  var rows = [],
      data;

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    rows.push([data.id, data.name,data.email]); //your JSON entities here
  }

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 3); // 3 Denotes total number of entites
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

}
```

**Edit 2**

Was able to get the number of open issues in the repo, and the number of closed issues in the repo, but to dump them to a specific cell is still very vague for me.

```
  var openPatches = "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:vizorvr/patches+state:open"
  var closedPatches = "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:vizorvr/patches+state:closed"

  var openResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(openPatches, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var Data = JSON.parse(openResponse.getContentText());
  Logger.log("Open issues on Patches GitHub:")
  Logger.log(Data.total_count)

  var closedresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(closedPatches, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var data = JSON.parse(closedresponse.getContentText());
  Logger.log("Closed issues on Patches GitHub:")
  Logger.log(data.total_count)
  Logger.log(Object.keys(data))
```

Could I in theory just write Data.total_count and data.total_count to different cells on a sheet, without having to have a google sheet open in another tab on the browser?

Comment: provide the sample JSON data

Comment: Try Google Search.  You'd be amazed how many times StackOverFlow.com shows up on the search. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552779/how-to-parse-json-response-in-google-app-script) to a possible answer.

Comment: Tags should not be forced into the title. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. By the other hand, you should describe you search/research efforts. Reference: [ask].

Comment: @Ritz ok I took the sample JSON data from the log and posted it to the post itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON response in Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552779/how-to-parse-json-response-in-google-app-script)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update, to write the data in to a specific sheet you need to use `getSheetByName` to write in to a specific sheet

```
var url ="<<SPREADSHEET URL>>";
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("<<SHEET NAME>>");
```

To store the values in different cell, you can define the range and set the values accordingly.

```
sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(Data.total_count); //Open issues
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(data.total_count); //Closed issues
```

Comment: does one specify the full URL to the sheet including http:// etc? This whole getActiveSpreadsheet throws me off for a spin, what if I don't have a single active sheet..

Comment: Yes you can specify the spreadsheet url...I have modified the answer