# How to get certain elements of a json string in google script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I have a JSON-string in my google-script and it looks like this:

```
{ "email": "email@email.com", "url": "http://www.url.com" }
```

Now i want to send an email to the email that is specified in the string.
How do i get the email element out of this JSON string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON response in Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552779/how-to-parse-json-response-in-google-app-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourJSONString);
var email = data.email
```