# How to get ImportXML to refresh

Tags: google-sheets, refresh

I'm trying to get the "Daily APR" to be updated on my google sheet, the ImportXML works, but only returns the value from 3 days ago, i.e "0.31% Daily" whereas the rates are updated every so often. (most recent is 0.2x%)

https://autofarm.network/bsc/281/

this was the ImportXML that works

=IMPORTXML("https://autofarm.network/bsc/281/","/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]")

Does anyone have any idea how to get the ImportXML to return me the most recent value and not the original value from when i scraped it 3 days ago?

Comment: Is the value always `0.31% Daily` when you use IMPORTXML? Also see my response to this similar question. I suspect it has to do with the fact that it is the JavaScript that updates this part. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67056410/10445017

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting latest result due the the value display come from `Json API` rather than write into the website, in such case, you will need to learn how to do web **scraping** using `Json` and also try to figure how to `0.18% daily` was calculated, go to the `website> Right click Inpect> Network> XHR`, from there, I only know how the `Share of pool` & `Total APY` were obtained, `0.18%` come from **formula**:

[image]

**Reference (How to perform JSon Parse)**

[How to parse JSON response in Google App Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552779/how-to-parse-json-response-in-google-app-script)